# Routing on GET request with client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

Similar situation to Julian here:
[MVC - Route with querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720679/mvc-route-with-querystring)

I can't grasp how to action a form, with GET request, with defined routes and values from form.

(EDIT: essentially same context in terms of problem as Julian's but asking about specific solution(s) in terms of javascript libary and/or custom routing (instead of general areas and explaining why there is an issue and different approach needed to given code); also not using *global.asax*; over a year since question meaning other options may be available too.)

As a beginner, it is difficult to get far with overwhelming client libraries and having little idea where to start with the relevant custom route provider, which however seems more preferable for simplicity of keeping server side routing and 301 redirect.

Tried different routes (apparently not 'custom') and looked into many libraries but really failing to make any tangible progress.

Any simple pointers e.g. routing example/key words/links, simple client code example (for this context etc.) would be very useful.

---

Using **[this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc-4-and-visual-studio-2011/examining-the-details-and-delete-methods) tutorial** to create a search page for movies, by **title** and **genre**.]

Here is my specific code:

**RouteConfig**:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Movies",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{title}/{genre}",
            defaults: new 
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index"
                }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new 
                { 
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
        );
    }
```

**ActionResult**:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string title, string genre)
{
            var genreQuery = from g in db.Movies
                         orderby g.Genre
                         select g.Genre;
            var genres = new List<string>();
            genres.AddRange(genreQuery.Distinct());
            ViewBag.Genre = new SelectList(genres);

            var movies = from m in db.Movies
                         select m;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(title));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(genre))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(s => s.Genre == genre);
            }

            return View(movies);
        }
```

SearchIndex.cshtml:

```
    @model IEnumerable<DefaultMvcIA.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SearchIndex";
}

<h2>SearchIndex</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchIndex", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>Genre: @Html.DropDownList("Genre", "All")
        Title: @Html.TextBox("Title")<br />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p>
    }
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.MovieID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.MovieID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.MovieID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**Problem**
On GET request browser just uses querystring and not set routing in RouteConfig (understandbly). Need to write custom route to redirect these querystrings to route OR use client library. Specific information really useful, as many different routing libraries out there and don't know where to start with (preferable) 301 custom routing method.

Comment: Do you have any code snippets?

Comment: More information about downvote appreciated. Understand similar question but so far no answer found about custom routing and library asked for in terms of scenario not just links and statements.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  Julian's question was specific; yours doesn't show any code, or give us any idea what problem you're facing.  You ask for "related client library code to scenario", but I have no idea what the scenario is.

Comment: Edited question: hopefully more clear it's very closely tied to linked question, but just asking for useful relevant snippets/links as lots of libraries and lots of routing options, so two points from Keith has not helped me progress.

Comment: please give a specific example of the kind of post url with querystirng you receive and what you would like it to do.

Comment: let me know if you have any remaining questions, if my answer has fully answered your questions, please mark it accordingly

Comment: Upvote for always being useful and informative as not sure of knowledge --> accepted for solution. Thank you for your persistent effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : 8:46 PM

The controller/action, ie. Search/Index can be overloaded to return different results depending on whether there is a querystring and whether it is a get request, etc.

```
public ActionResult Index(){} will be hit by host/ControllerName/Index

public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm) will be hit by host/ControllerName/Index?searchTerm=ABC
```

EDIT: 9:23 AM

if you need to change the action to which it posts dynamically, there are javascript libraries that will intercept the get request. If you don't mind using ajax, you can always look into http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/ to intercept the form request and you can change the link to whatever you want it to be.

EDIT: 6/16  9:22 AM
in the code above, there is the line

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchIndex", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
```

This indicates that the Get request will perform a "Get" request to the "SearchIndexController" and the "Movies" ActionResult.

(so it still uses the code in the global.asax routing to route to that controller/action) This routing code in global.asax is *always* used for every request.

---

Edits in resoponse to focus on how to access querystrings (to reroute a path)

you can bind to the querystring directly. To avoid duplicating text on other answers, see 
[ASP.NET MVC - Getting QueryString values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627838/asp-net-mvc-getting-querystring-values) for some ways to get a value from a querysting.

If you dont want to bind to them directly in the ActionResult method signature, use the Request.Querystring object to access the querystring. ie.

```
 var searchTerm = Request.QueryString["searchTerm"].ToString();
 var sortColumn = Request.QueryString["sortColumn"].ToString();
```

or

```
 var searchTerms = Request.QueryString["searchTerms"].ToString().SplitBy(",")
```

depending on the syntax of the querystirng...

to redirect a method based on the result of a querystring parameter, you can always return a different action method, or you can redirect to Action

```
 ie. return this.Index2( ..param...);
```

or

```
 RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName")
```

... there are many ways to redirect to an action of your choice.

---

How to "action" a form isn't really making sense to me.

In mvc, a simple setup is to have a form like

```
@{using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Post)){
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Word)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Word, new { @Value = Model.Word})
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

where "Index" is the action name and "Home" is the controller name. This would be routed to the Action method of the HomeController. This routing path can actually be customized in the routing specified in Global.asax. In global.asax, there are code snippets that look like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This would route urls of the form A/B/C to AController, ActionResult B with parameter Id=3

I hope this is enough information to help you look for a suitable tutorial to follow. If you are still a student (or still have a college email or have a friend with one), watch videos at http://www.pluralsight.com/training They have great introductory videos that can help you learn mvc3/4 basics.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer! The problem is I'm using a GET request and due to this the routing I've set - like Julian in the linked question - querystrings are used on the request as understandably the browser doesn't know the routes I set. So I'm looking to write a custom route to do a 301 redirect ideally, but there are apparently also libraries on the client side that GET the form with client-set routes - just many of which differ and I can't really get far with them. Maybe I could take a better approach to a search than the tutorials to allow routing? But it seems pretty robust.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're asking, you can access the query strings in the controller. You're trying to use the query strings to redirect to another controller? You can do that too.

Comment: I want to use routes instead of the query string which the browser uses for the GET request, but I don't know how to write customer 301 route in RouteConfig (and libraries vary in type, size and use - I don't know where to start with them, but prefer cutom route option). Edited the answer with my actual code and problem in context.

Comment: Thank you for the useful edits. Yes I'm using a get request with the same controller and actionresult, so if routing is used for every request I apparently shouldn't be experiencing querystrings? Also experiencing other strange behaviour: http://localhost:xxxx/Movies/SearchIndex triggers the search textbox to fill with 'SearchIndex' when it is an action, not argument for title parameter. Plus after pressing filter with this 'SearchIndex' in TB I get http://localhost:xxx/Movies/SearchIndex?Genre=&Title=SearchIndex to give the specific querystrings I get. MY routes are problem maybe?

Comment: I meant that the routing in global.asax is used to determine the route for every request. Also, I find it likely you have the same action SearchIndex repeated multiple times in the controller. In each instace it accepts different parameters and returns a different result (its called overloading). Querystrings are the result of the get request automatically appending the information on the form to the url. It is expected and normal as well.